# I have 4 videos on same webpage, with play, pause skip. but the video's interect with each other

Tags: video, html

I want to play four different videos on my website. However, when I push the play button on the second video, the first one reacts.

Here's my code so far:

```
<button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play 
Video</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">Pause 
Video</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://ivanflo.sytes.net/cms1/index.php?
 page=bipolair';" id="Button01" class="float-left submit-button" >Skip 
 Video</button></br>
 <video id="myVideo01" width="100%" >
 <source 
 src="http://hetmosterdzaadje.be/
 Very%20angry%20man%20Destroying%20his%20car%20completely.mp4" 
 type="video/mp4">
 </video>
 <script> 
 var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo01"); 
 function playVid() { 
 vid.play(); 
 } 
 function pauseVid() { 
 vid.pause(); 
 } 
 </script>
```

Every script is the same except for the video contents.

Every script has its own "block", but I could put them all into one block if I needed to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use different function names for each video..

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the first video only to the vid variable.

To have the same functions serve all or any amount of videos, you'll have to make it more generic, may be as follows:

```
<script> 
function playVid(vidID) { 
    var vid = document.getElementById(vidID); 
    vid.play(); 
} 
function pauseVid(vidID) { 
    var vid = document.getElementById(vidID); 
    vid.pause(); 
}
</script>
```

And in your html

```
<button onclick="playVid('myVideo001')" type="button">Play Video</button>
```

Notice that now you're passing the video ID to each function.